# Simple Jquery Ajax External Page Content Load

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is my first day coding and using jquery, I figured the best way to learn is practise.
I want to remove content from #container and add new content from an external page.
Should be quite straight forward right?
I have this so far, but it doesn't work every time. Any assistance would be great.

js

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.nav a').click(function(){

      var url = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

      window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-5);

      $('#container').load(url);

      return false;       

  });
});
```

index.html

```
<html>

<body>

<div id="container">


    <div id="content">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" id="about">About</a>
            index
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and about.html

```
<body>

<div id="container">


    <div id="content">
        <div class="nav">
            <a href="index.html" id="home">Home</a>
            <a href="about.html" id="about">About</a>
            about
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

at the moment it only works every other click.

Thanks for looking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're replacing your original HTML elements with new ones that you load. But at the same time the `click` event handlers get removed along with the elements and no longer work.

In older versions of `jQuery` you could overcome this using `live()` instead of `click()`, but with the latest versions - I'm not up to date. I'm sure someone here will add their $0.02 to help.

Edit: Turns out you can use `on()`

```
$(document).on("click", ".nav a", function() {
    //code goes here
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I'm removing the .nav menu thus ruining the jquery functionality. But effectively I want to be able to load and replace a whole page. Is there a different way to do this without losing the jquery functionality.<br/>I can't seem to get the .on("click" running...

Comment: You will have to provide more details. What error message do you get if any? What version of jQuery are you using? Did you read the jQuery docs on `on()` and `live()`?

Comment: Sorry made a simple error, This works great. Looks like I have a lot more practising to do. Slightly daunted but hope I get good soon. Thanks for the help! Accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You replace the contents of .nav, which contains the html with jquery handlers.

- First click, replaces the .nav menu - loss of jquery functionality.
- Second click, conventional hyperlink - reloads page - jquery functionality returns.

To get yourself started try loading something into an element other than .nav and not within .nav .

Comment: Thanks, I understand that I'm removing the .nav menu thus ruining the jquery functionality. But effectively I want to be able to load and replace a whole page. Is there a different way to do this without losing the jquery functionality.